# Add date and time manully in django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I want to add date and time manually for required task but when i add date & time and submit it show error of null field.

Model.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class TaskList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    task = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    datetimepicker1 = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
```

View.py

```
def post(self, request):
    if SESSION_KEY in self.request.session:
        try:
            data = self.request.POST.get
            task_list = TaskList(
                user_id=request.session[SESSION_KEY],
                task=data('task'),
                datetimepicker1=data('datetimepicker1')
            )
            task_list.save()
            return redirect('todolist')
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse('failed {}'.format(e), 500)
```

Template

```
  <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="task">
                    <input name="task" placeholder="add today's task" id="task" required>
                </label>
              <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
                  <label for="datetimepicker1">
                        <input class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" type="text" id="datetimepicker1" required>
                  </label>
                <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
                  <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">add</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
import datetime
def post(self, request):
    datetimepicker1 = request.POST.get('datetimepicker1')
    datetimepicker1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimepicker1,'%Y-%m-%d')
    if SESSION_KEY in self.request.session:
        try:
            data = self.request.POST.get
            task_list = TaskList(
                .....
                datetimepicker1 = datetimepicker1
            )
            ......
            return HttpResponse('failed {}'.format(e), 500)
```

change datetimepicker1 to datetime

Comment: datetimepicker1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(datetimepicker1,'%Y-%m-%d')
it show error on this line unresolved attribute reference datetime for class datetime

Comment: from django.utils.datetime_safe import datetime

Comment: just import datetime, no need to from django.utils.datetime_safe

Comment: Now it show the error. " strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None"

Comment: in html <input class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" type="text" id="datetimepicker1" required> add name='datetimepicker1'

Comment: Thanks u so much for help